# The three wars against Amalek

Tags: amalek

i recall reading that there was\will be three wars with Amalek.

The first was with Shaul, the Second with Mordechai and the third will be by moshiach.

Has anyone heard this? Or know where it is discussed?

Comment: Isn’t the first the one described in Parashat Beshalach, with the fighting led by Yehoshua?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be found in the [Ohr Hachaim HaKadosh](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.17.14?lang=bi&with=Or%20HaChaim&lang2=en#:%7E:text=The%20repetition%20of%20the%20words%20%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%97%D7%94%2C%20may%20be%20an%20allusion%20to%20two%20occasions%20when%20a%20major%20battle%20would%20be%20fought%20against%20Amalek%2C%20one%20by%20King%20Saul%2C%20the%20other%20by%20Mordechai.) on the last pasuk of Parshas Beshalach

Answer (score 1):

The first war with Amalek is discussed in [sefer Shmuel](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.15.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> Now go and smite ῾Amaleq, and utterly destroy all that they have, and spare them not; but slay both man and woman, infant and suckling, ox and sheep, camel and ass.

The second one, Mordechai. Mordechai was an descendant of Shaul. Haman was an descendant of [Agag, who was spared](https://www.sefaria.org/I_Samuel.15.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

[See:](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/2301416/jewish/The-Everlasting-Battle.htm) Likkutei Sichos, Vol. III, pp. 913-915; Vol. XXII, pp. 190-196

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the final war, it is continuous and has been going on continually, but yes it will be finished finally by H"Y Himself through the hand of the Moshe-Mashiach like the first time. So in that sense there are more than three wars; it's continuous but with breaks like when Moshe Rabbeinu raised his hand and the Bene Yisrael prevailed.

This war will be by H"Y His Very Self through the hand of the Moshe-Mashiach as it says, "sworn by His Hand on the Throne of YK, a war to YKWK, era to era."

There are 17 mentions of Amalek in Tikkunei Zohar, and for example on daf 18 it says just by saying Kriat Shema you slay Amalek basically. Because Amalek is gematria Safek, doubt, the opposite of faith, as is commonly known.

Here is a piece from Tikkun 69, end, mentioning that prayer and calling on H"Y will begin when the Moshe-Mashiach will come and fight shepherd vs. shepherd and slay Amalek.

ועוד אז הוחל לישנא דצלותא, כמה דאת אמר אז תקרא וה' יענה, דא הוא נטורא טבא, דאף על גב דהבל קטיל ליה קין, דמניה הוה נפיק מאן דנוקים ליה, הדא הוא דכתיב (שמות ט"ו) אז ישיר משה, רועה נוקים לרועה, ולבתר אז אהפוך אל עמים שפה ברורה לקרא כלם בשם ה', אבל כד עמלק דאינון:

תיקוני זהר דף קיט/ב

בכורי מצרים ערב רב מעורבין בישראל, עלייהו אתמר תמחה את זכר עמלק, דלא אשתאר מנהון שריד, דאלין אינון ערבוביא מכל אומין ואפילו מקין, ומיד דיתמחון מעלמא אז הוחל לקרא בשם ה':

...
"And then shall begin the language of prayer, as it is said, 'Then you shall call, and the Lord will answer.' For that is a good protection, even though Abel's blood cried out to him, as his likeness emerged from those who afflicted him. This is what is written (Exodus 15): 'Then Moses sang,' comparing suffering to suffering. And afterwards, I will turn to the nations with a clear language, all calling in the name of the Lord. But as for Amalek, they are cunning:

Zohar Corrections, page 159/b
The firstborn of Egypt, mixed among the Israelites, about them it is said, 'You shall surely erase the memory of Amalek,' for none of them should remain as a remnant. They are mixed from all nations, even from Cain. And as soon as they are erased from existence, then began the reading in the name of the Lord."
End Tikkun 69